# Insights required to repair my Agilent YIG oscillator

Tags: oscillator, repair, microwave

I know, it's probably no chance. But let me try.

The model is HP-Agilent 0955-0520, Y088-4258, that can be bought for 600-900$. 
Here is a picture.
[image]

When I bought the oscillator, I performed multiple tests and everything worked fine. Recently, the oscillator is no more able to deliver its 15dmb, but deliver only -15dmb (and there are resonances at intervals of 3GHz). The delivered power is still (surprisingly) flat, and the frequency is still tunable as previously. I've checked everything possible regarding the supply current, heater etc., and everything works as in the original tests. I suspect two possible things:

- somehow, the sma connector has been damaged
- the transistor has been damaged by some electrostatic discharge (I've very stupidly forgotten to protect it with a Zenner)

Unfortunately, I was unable to find anything technical regarding this model (and more generally, about most YIG oscillators). It seems my only chance is that a charitable person well acquainted with those models will give me some information...

Anyway, any insight will be appreciated before I try to open it.

Comment: I would do a check to see if the SMA connector still makes good contact. Maybe there is a (small) DC voltage present on the SMA output when the oscillator is running. Just use a multimeter to measure the DC voltage, then attach an SMA cable and measure again at the other end of the cable. The voltages should match, if not there might not be a proper contact. An alternative is to test using resistance (or diode) measurement mode but then all power to the oscillator must be off.

Comment: If the SMA connector isn't making good contact you could see what you see, the RF power is there but much smaller. That's because the SMA output only couples capacitively into the cable. That's a real bummer and a trap for RF newbies. You still get a signal (it still works a bit) when a connector is bad unlike at DC where you usually just get nothing at all.

Comment: Yes, that's the first thing I thought about, but the new resonances are unexplained. I've not very well understood why you think there should be a DC voltage at the sma pin. The only way I see to check the connector contacts it is to open the oscillator and to measure the resistance from the inside to the outside. Can you elaborate?

Comment: *I've not very well understood why you think there should be a DC voltage at the sma pin* I wrote *Maybe there is a (small) DC voltage...* If I look at some schematics of such a device there could be a DC voltage present. It depends on the design. The DC voltage should not be large (less than 0.5 V DC) as that could damage some devices. It is also very likely that there is no DC voltage at all.

Comment: YIG Oscillator output frequency ( 2 to 10 GHz) is controlled by the amount of current through the main and FM coils. The main coil is used to set the frequency and for FM ≤230 Hz. The FM coil is used for FM rates >230 Hz. I don't know the specs.

Comment: I've used the oscillator several times and I know how to drive the frequency with an adjustable current source. That's not exactly the point, but thank you anyway.